# crontab non executed in docker

Tags: docker, cron

I need to execute crontab inside docker container, so I created the following dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-oraclelinux8

RUN mkdir -p /opt/my-user/
RUN mkdir -p /opt/my-user/joblogs
RUN groupadd my-user && adduser my-user -g my-user
RUN chown -R my-user:my-user /opt/my-user/
RUN microdnf install yum
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install cronie
RUN yum -y install vi
RUN yum -y install telnet
COPY talend /opt/my-user/
COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/my-user/
RUN chmod +x /opt/my-user/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/my-user/ETLJob/ETLJob_run.sh
RUN chown -R my-user:my-user /opt/my-user/
RUN echo "*/2 * * * * /bin/sh /opt/my-user/ETLJob/ETLJob_run.sh >> /opt/my-user/joblogs/job.log 2>&1" >> /etc/cron.d/my-user-job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/my-user-job
RUN crontab -u my-user /etc/cron.d/my-user-job
RUN chmod u+s /usr/sbin/crond
USER my-user:my-user
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/my-user/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

My `entrypoint.sh` file is the following one:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start cron"
crontab /etc/cron.d/diomedee-job
echo "cron started"

# Run forever
tail -f /dev/null
```

So far so good, the container is created successfully and when I go inside the container and I type `crontab -l` I see the crontab... but it is never executed

I can't figure out what I'm missing; any research I made didn't give me any clue

May you give me any tip?

Comment: The command you want to run inside your container is `cron` (and not `crontab`....). Typing "running cron inside docker container" in your favorite search engine will give you dozens of results with examples depending on your specific use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers usually only host a single process. In your case, the `tail` process. The cron daemon isn't running.

Your comment 'cron started' seems to indicate that running `crontab` starts the daemon, but it doesn't.

Replace your `tail -f /dev/null` command with `crond -f` to run the cron daemon in the foreground and it should work.

Comment: I was sure i was missing something stupid :) thank you. Just a note... for oraclelinux 8 the command is `crond -n`